# UIBarButtonItem in iOS 7 not showing correctly

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I have this image:

[image]

that I am using as a leftBarButtonItem and in iOS 6 it shows correctly, but in iOS 7 it is showing like this:

[image]

Here is the code to add the button, which I am doing in viewDidLoad.

```
UIBarButtonItem * btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btHomeTouched:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
```

I am basically trying to have my UITableViewController look as it did in iOS 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItem with UIImage Always Tinted iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372269/uibarbuttonitem-with-uiimage-always-tinted-ios-7)

Comment: Yes it was, the duplicate solution worked!!