# UIBarButtonItem is blue but should be gray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add some buttons to my UINavigationBar. It seems I can't just drag and drop an item into the bar, is this correct? So I a using this code below but for some reason the cog icon I am using is appearing as blue but it's actually a gray colour. How can I use the original image colour? Any help would be appreciated!

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cog"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify rendering mode when creating image, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19669169/1948606) answer:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cog"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the **tint color** of your navigation bar or the `UIBarButtonItem` to achieve the desired result.

If you need to change the tint color in the whole app, update the `[UINavigationBar appearance]` in your *AppDelegate.m*