# iOS: Why is custom tab bar item showing only as grey silhouette?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to set the tab bar icons of my UITabBarController with custom *.png files (one for the selected and one for unselected).

The images are all in non-interlaced png format and are named correctly (@2x, @3x, etc) residing in an *.imageset.

But the tab bar items are only shown as silhouettes like this:

[image]

I tried to set these images within Interface Builder, without success. Then I also tried to set them programmatically in the "loadView" function of MyTabBarController (which is extending UITabBarController) like this:

```
UIImage *selectedImage;
UIImage *unselectedImage;

// tab1
selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdGamesActive"];
unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdGamesInactive"];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
item1 = [item1 initWithTitle:@"Games" image:unselectedImage selectedImage:selectedImage];

// tab2
selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdFriendsActive"];
unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdFriendsInactive"];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
item2 = [item2 initWithTitle:@"Friends" image:unselectedImage selectedImage:selectedImage];

// tab3
selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdTrophiesActive"];
unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdTrophiesInactive"];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
item3 = [item3 initWithTitle:@"Trophies" image:unselectedImage selectedImage:selectedImage];

// tab4
selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdSettingsActive"];
unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cmdSettingsInactive"];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
item4 = [item4 initWithTitle:@"Settings" image:unselectedImage selectedImage:selectedImage];
```

... with the same result.

**Any ideas how to solve this issue ?**

Comment: complete the image name try adding .png in the end.

Comment: @Samraan Khaan: Thanks, but this didn't help. Funnily enough, it works with another image that only features transparency and some white in it. But my icons are pretty colorful... Any further ideas?

Comment: @cookiemonsta: It looks like it's not possible with the new iOS SDK's ... Only b/w images supported that are tinted when selected.

Comment: Ahh shucks! Thank you for the update :)

Comment: @cookiemonsta: Have a look on this thread. It describes a very similar problem with tab bar items. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372269/uibarbuttonitem-with-uiimage-always-tinted-ios-7

Comment: @salocinx : Sir, great help! Thanks. I did however update it. Hopefully it helped you too, if not, how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32369370/3359372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19669169/3359372), I did something extra and kind of have answer for you here. I have my custom UITabBarController, which is linked with my UITabBarController in the StoryBoard file. So in order to remove the automatic tint provided by iOS when the TabBar is unselected, I ended up removing it in this manner. The images can be a vast variety of images but just in the way [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19669169/3359372). Here it goes:

```
NSArray *navConArr = self.viewControllers;//self is custom UITabBarController
UINavigationController *naviOne = [navConArr objectAtIndex:0];//I have 3 different tabs, objectAtIndex:0 means the first tab navigation controller
UITabBarItem *naviBtn  = naviOne.tabBarItem;
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconNaviOne"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[naviBtn setSelectedImage:image];
[naviBtn setImage:image];
```

Thankfully, this works like a charm (:

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue.
I had chosen few icons for my tabs such as 'mic', 'smiley' and 'settings'.

But the only things visible when I executed the program were grey and blue squares.

I modified my '.png' images to be transparent and now they are visible as they were intended to.

i.e, make sure the images used for tab icons do not have a background.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
UITabBarItem *item0 = [_tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
item0.image  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_profile_tab"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
item0.selectedImage  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_profile_tab_active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```