# Tracking a UIBarButtonItem selected state?

Tags: ios, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uiappearance

Is there a way to highlight (i.e., toggle) a `UIBarButtonItem` without using a custom view?

For example, see **3D** button from the *Maps* app:

[image: Maps app]

or **Shuffle All** from the *Music* app:

[image: Music App]

Comment: possible duplicate of [programmatically highlight UIBarButtonItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267758/programmatically-highlight-uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: Check out my answer to basically the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320847/how-to-set-uibarbuttonitem-selected-or-highlighted-image-or-tint-colours-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background image of the `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
item.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "item-bg.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Then when you want to de-select it, set the background image to `nil`:

```
item.setBackgroundImage(nil, forState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

(You have to create an image file for the background)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that wile UIControl has an `isSelected` property that achieves this goal, `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't inherit from that, so you can't cast it and set the value. However, there's a strange workaround I discovered. If you set the type for the `sender` of the button's action as `UIControl`, it will be treated as a full-blown UIControl, and you can set `isSelected`.

for example:

```swift
    @objc func showContentsView(_ sender: UIControl) { 
        sender.isSelected.toggle()
    }
```

If you need to toggle the state elsewhere, you can have a variable on your View Controller like this:

```swift
var selectedControl: UIControl?
```

Set the value of `selectedControl` in your action and set it to `nil` when unselecting it.

Comment: Interesting, but probably not very future safe unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

```
item.image = UIImage(named: isSelected ? "SelectedImage" : "NormalImage")
```